# How to restore the previous state of the App when the App is gone for sleep or on resume in xamarin forms(Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have no idea about this. I'm new to the xamarin forms.

regards

Comment: can you explain what you mean by state of app?

Comment: last used content page

Comment: It doesn't change the page when you go to sleep and then resume the app

Comment: its changing for me

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to but there is one life-cycle event in xamarin forms OnResume() which can override in app.cs. There you can achieve what you want on resume app.

Comment: If the app is killed (typically due to the OS needing memory), it will restart from scratch. If you need it to be restored to a particular page, you need to save the state of the app every time the app goes to sleep, on start (or restart in this case), you need to read that state, restore the app and goto whatever page you need it restored to.

Comment: @SushiHangover will try that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have just removed noHistory=true in my android project that makes me good